# Solarium not extract PDF content

Tags: solarium

Today I am using extract first time. Solarium extracts metadata from a PDF document and inserted into the index, but does not save the content. I used the example **2.7 Extract query** (from Solarium examples) and replaced it *index.html* with *myfile.pdf* but does not work. Anyone know what happens? thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem. I don't know why but, changing

$query->addFieldMapping('content', 'text');

to

$query->addFieldMapping('fmap.content', 'text');

did work for me.

Maybe the problem is in solrconfig.xml definition of /update/extract RequestHandler

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="fmap.content">text</str>
<str name="lowernames">true</str>
<str name="uprefix">attr_</str>
<str name="captureAttr">true</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I have also verified that, extracting data from Html file, does not work as expected without applying the modification i have explained before. If you run again extraction test with 'fmap.content' you will see the content of html page mapped in 'content' field.

I made those test with Solr 4.4.0 and Solarium 3.1.2

hope it helps

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment.